# ListStatusChanges to get status based on the individual recipients

Tags: docusignapi

We have multiple recipients per envelope and the signing order is set. Can we get the envelope based on the status of individual recipients?. I don't see anything that we can do to achieve this through ListStatusChangesOptions. I know that we can achieve this by listRecipients but this did not give us an option to set parameters to limit the data, like ListStatusChangesOptions.

I want to reduce the API call limit, if there is an option to directly limit the data sent from DocuSign based on the status of the individual recipients.
Eg: Get all the Envelopes whose recipient1 status is completed.
Instead of getting more than required envelopes through listStatusChanges and limiting them by using listRecipients

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API call to fetch envelope details based on recipient status. Instead I would propose to use `DocuSign Connect`. It has trigger event of Recipient Signed, so once recipient has signed you will get a message from DocuSign with envelope details like envelopeId, which recipient Signed it etc, and this will save a lot of your API calls and DocuSign Connect is the recommended way from DocuSign instead of doing polling. You can learn more about DS Connect here,

- https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/custom-connect-configuration.htm
- https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf

Comment: Is there any sample java code for DocuSign connect client?